# How to store reminders from Google Now offline?

Tags: google-now, voice-recognition, offline, ok-google, reminders

I find it very convenient to set reminders using voice "OK Google" with Google Now. However, I cannot seem to get it to work when I do not have an internet connection.

Is there a way I can set reminders with voice that will also work when offline?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the calendar. Press the plus button, the reminders option will come up. It has slightly fewer options to it but is still a useful reminder.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the time on your phone and then go to alarms and set it up.

Comment: Could you describe the process more fully please? Your answer could be helpful if you make it clearer what steps to follow.

Comment: Well, it seems this sets a generic alarm on the phone. Whether it can be called as reminder or not, it's questionable.